# ELB Connection Draining Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, autoscaling

So, we are kinda kinda lost using the AWS ELB connection draining feature.
We have an Auto Scaling Group and we have an application that has independent sessions (A session on every instance). We configured the ELB listener over HTTP on port 80, forwarding to port 8080 (this is of course the port where the application is deployed) and we created a LBCookieStickinessPolicy. We also enabled the connection draining for 120 seconds.

[image]

- The behavior we want:
  We want to scale down an instance but since the session is sticked to each instance, we want to "maintain" that session during 120 seconds (Or the connection draining configuration).
- The behavior we have: 
  We have tried to deregister, set to stanby, terminate, stop, set to unhealthy an instance. But no matter what we do, the instance shut downs immediately causing the session to end abruptly. Also, we changed the ELB listener configuration to work over TCP with no luck.

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you make any progess with this? We're looking at Auto-scaling in conjunction with an ELBv2, but want the same scenario: connection draining on an instance that is nominated for termination.

Comment: @kafka No, actually, the given answer was pretty accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection draining refers to open tcp connections with the client it has nothing to do with sessions on your instance. You may be able to do something with keep-alives if you do a TCP passthrough instead of http listener.

The best route to go is set up sessions to be shared between your instances and then disable stickyness on the load balancer.

Comment: I am totally restricted to see the code and they will not take the sessions out, that is why I have to workaround like this. When you say a "TCP passthrough instead of http listener" you mean, changing the listener from HTTP to TCP?

Comment: @TachúSalamanca Correct, there is no guarantee that this will work. But by adjusting keepalive settings you may be able to keep the TCP connection open longer.

Comment: We already changed it, "Also, we changed the ELB listener configuration to work over TCP with no luck."